# MYSQL, Need List of All Dates and First Date

Tags: mysql

Sorry for the simple question, but I need a list of all customer transactions, the date of that transaction, and the date of their first transaction. I know the code below doesn't work but was seeing if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

```
SELECT 
    Location, Date, ?Min(Date)?
FROM
    Transactions
```

```
Location      Date      First Date
   A        1/3/2020     1/3/2020
   A        1/5/2020     1/3/2020
   B        1/4/2020     1/4/2020
   B        1/8/2020     1/4/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the table with a subquery that gets the first transaction date.

```
SELECT t.Location, t.Date, t1.MinDate
FROM Transactions AS t
JOIN (
    SELECT Location, MIN(Date) AS MinDate
    FROM Transactions
    GROUP BY Location
) AS t1 ON t.Location = t1.Location
```